# Searching tweets with RStudio and Shiny

Tags: r, twitter, shiny, twitter-oauth

I`m trying to write a simple app to get tweets from twitter api and show them in a table with shiny. 
At the end, I also want to store them, but I'm not finished yet...

Here ist my code, 
Code:

```
library(twitteR)
library (shiny)

  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(4, textInput("searchkw", label = "search:", value = "#movie")),

      column(8, tableOutput('table'))
    )
  )

  server = function(input, output) {

    # OAuth authentication
    consumer_key <- ("XXX")
    consumer_secret <- ("XXX")
    access_token <- ("XXX")
    access_secret<-("XXX")

    options(httr_oauth_cache = TRUE) # enable using a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions
    setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

    # Issue search query to Twitter
    dataInput <- reactive({  
      data <- twListToDF(searchTwitter(input$searchkw, n = 10),
      data$created <- as.character(data$created)
    )})


    # Create a reactive table 
    data$table <- renderTable(
      dataInput()[, c("text", "screenName")]
    )
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

but I get the error:

> "Error in data$table <- renderTable(dataInput()[, c("text", "screenName")]) : 
>     object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Can anyone here help me with this problem? 
Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: In `dataInput` you should add `data` as the last line, since you are not returning the object.

Comment: Do you mean like that? 
dataInput()[, c("text", "screenName", data())]
Unfortunately, it isn’t working in my app like that… Do you have other ideas?
Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: No, not at all. I meant in the definition of `dataInput`: after `data$created <- as.character(data$created)`, put a line with just `data`.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this line didn't change anything...

Comment: I missed the obvious: `data$table<-renderTable(...)` is wrong and  should be replaced with `output$table<-renderTable(...)`.

Comment: Thank you very mch for your help :) This error is gone